# How to set zoom in zoom out and reduce default zoom size?

Tags: android

i follow this tutorial http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c16ed3b4-b422-43ba-b595-ee8e21dd1854 problem is when i capture image is default show is size so big but all zoom in zoom out how to i set is default size to normal image size?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

   view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

   float scale;



   // Dump touch event to log

   dumpEvent(event);



   // Handle touch events here...

   switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {



   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only

      savedMatrix.set(matrix);

      start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );

      mode = DRAG;

      break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted

      mode = NONE;

      Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );

      break;

   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down

      oldDist = spacing(event);

      Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);

      if (oldDist > 5f) {

         savedMatrix.set(matrix);

         midPoint(mid, event);

         mode = ZOOM;

         Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );

      }

      break;



   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger

         matrix.set(savedMatrix);

         if (view.getLeft() >= -392){

            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);

         }
      }

      else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming

         float newDist = spacing(event);

         Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);

         if (newDist > 5f) {

            matrix.set(savedMatrix);

            scale = newDist / oldDist; /*thinking i need to play around  
with this value to limit it*/

            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

         }

      }

      break;

   }



   // Perform the transformation

   view.setImageMatrix(matrix);



   return true; // indicate event was handled

}



private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {

   float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);

   float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

   return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

}



private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {

   float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);

   float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);

   point.set(x / 2, y / 2);

}



/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */

private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {

   String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,

      "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   int action = event.getAction();

   int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

   sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);

   if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN

         || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {

      sb.append("(pid " ).append(

      action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);

      sb.append(")" );

   }

   sb.append("[" );

   for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {

      sb.append("#" ).append(i);

      sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));

      sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));

      sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));

      if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())

         sb.append(";" );

   }

   sb.append("]" );

   Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float initialZoomLevel = 0.5f;
matrix.setScale(initialZoomLevel, initialZoomLevel);
view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

put this in the constructor / initilization method for your image view. This will cause the image to immediately be displayed at 1/2 size. Any further modifications to the image should be done on the same matrix

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    matrix = view.getImageMatrix()
    //.. now do zooming, etc on this matrix
}
```

This way, the "default" size of the image is set to half of the original. Hope this helps!